# Tensorflow: feeding placeholder in loop within loop fails

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am trying to repeatedly train a neural network at different sizes of hidden layer to determine how many neurons it should be. I wrote a net that works fine when doing one pass through. The code is:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import nn

def train(layers, data, folder = 'run1'):
    input_layer_size, hidden_layer_size, num_labels = layers;
    X, y, X_val, y_val = data;

    X_placeholder = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(None, input_layer_size), name='X')
    y_placeholder = tf.placeholder(tf.uint8, shape=(None, num_labels), name='y')
    Theta1 = tf.Variable(nn.randInitializeWeights(input_layer_size, hidden_layer_size), name='Theta1')
    bias1 = tf.Variable(nn.randInitializeWeights(hidden_layer_size, 1), name='bias1')
    Theta2 = tf.Variable(nn.randInitializeWeights(hidden_layer_size, num_labels), name='Theta2')
    bias2 = tf.Variable(nn.randInitializeWeights(num_labels, 1), name='bias2')
    cost = nn.cost(X_placeholder, y_placeholder, Theta1, bias1, Theta2, bias2)
    optimize = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.6).minimize(cost)

    accuracy, precision, recall, f1 = nn.evaluate(X_placeholder, y_placeholder, Theta1, bias1, Theta2, bias2)

    cost_summary = tf.summary.scalar('cost', cost);
    accuracy_summary = tf.summary.scalar('accuracy', accuracy);
    precision_summary = tf.summary.scalar('precision', precision);
    recall_summary = tf.summary.scalar('recall', recall);
    f1_summary = tf.summary.scalar('f1', f1);
    summaries = tf.summary.merge_all();

    sess = tf.Session();
    saver = tf.train.Saver()
    init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
    sess.run(init)

    writer = tf.summary.FileWriter('./tmp/logs/' + folder, sess.graph)

    NUM_STEPS = 20;

    for step in range(NUM_STEPS):
        sess.run(optimize, feed_dict={X_placeholder: X, y_placeholder: y});
        if (step > 0) and ((step + 1) % 10 == 0):
            summary = sess.run(summaries, feed_dict={X_placeholder: X_val, y_placeholder: y_val});
            # writer.add_summary(summary, step);
            print('Step', step + 1, 'of', NUM_STEPS);

    save_path = saver.save(sess, './tmp/model_' + folder + '.ckpt')
    print("Model saved in file: %s" % save_path)
    sess.close();
```

When I put this call in a loop however, I make it through only the first iteration. It seems to fail during the second iteration the first time I hit this line:

```
summary = sess.run(summaries, feed_dict={X_placeholder: X_val, y_placeholder: y_val});
```

I get the error: `InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'X' with dtype float`

I logged both `X` and `X_val` right before feeding and they look exactly like they do on each preceding run. If I comment that second `run` part out it works great, but I kinda need my summaries...

My outer loop looks like this:

```
import train
import loadData

input_layer_size  = 5513;
num_labels = 128;

data = loadData.load(input_layer_size, num_labels);

for hidden_layer_size in range(50, 500, 50):
    train.train([input_layer_size, hidden_layer_size, num_labels], data, 'run' + str(hidden_layer_size))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you call the train function inside a loop then each time it runs it is creating a new copy of the placeholders. The first time it runs it is fine because there is only one copy. The second time it runs now you have duplicate placeholders. The solution is to separate out the code that builds the model from the code that runs the training.

Comment: Still wrapping my head around tensorflow. Are placeholders cached somehow even after I close a session? I figured that because I create and close a new session every time I call this, everything would be created fresh then destroyed.

Comment: you need to call `tf.reset_default_graph()`, otherwise the graph is stored in your Python runtime and is unaffected by session closing

Comment: Use one session do to the training. Don't create a new session inside the training loop.

Comment: Ah it's the graph that I need to refresh/recreate, not session? If I do that, will my variables reset as they do now?

Comment: Neither the graph nor the session should be reset during training. If you reset the graph the variables will reset.

Comment: In this case I want the variables to reset. I want to go through many full training rounds, each one with a different number of hidden neurons.

Comment: creating a new `tf.Graph` and putting my graph code inside a `with graph.as_default():` block solved this issue for me.